# Touchpad randomly stops working after installing Windows 10 (Dual boot)

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, keyboard, touchpad

I have a Razer Blade 15" (2018). Never had an issue with the touchpad or the keyboard running PopOS or Arch (Single boot). I had to install Windows 10 alongside PopOS for a job and when I came back to PopOS, the touchpad randomly froze making it unusable for a couple minutes while the keyboard still responded. It never happened before and it still does not happen when I'm using Windows. The drivers didn't change in my PopOS installation. I also had this issue while doing a GRUB reinstall on a live Ubuntu USB key after installing Windows 10.

Is there a chance that the Windows installation messed something up? Could this be kernel related?

P.-S. : I should mention that this Razer Blade model has a NVIDIA GTX 1060.

**Update 1**

Here is the dmesg errors when the issue appears.

```
   [890.011405] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[  976.035502] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[  976.035510] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 163 write_ptr 164
[  976.283612] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[  976.291130] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  976.291132] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: -8163490
[  976.291133] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0
[  976.291134] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x72A5BF0E | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
    [  976.291134] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x2BF7D36D | trm_hw_status0
    [  976.291135] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x8C1C7DC3 | trm_hw_status1
    [  976.291136] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x287BFABD | branchlink2
    [  976.291137] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x34A2855F | interruptlink1
    [  976.291137] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB430FECC | interruptlink2
    [  976.291138] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x46C2EBC1 | data1
    [  976.291139] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xBFFF933D | data2
    [  976.291139] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xAC2DC804 | data3
    [  976.291140] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xF7FF6E2F | beacon time
    [  976.291141] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB30B9B83 | tsf low
    [  976.291141] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x97661639 | tsf hi
    [  976.291142] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x091D9000 | time gp1
    [  976.291143] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xCEBF5E94 | time gp2
    [  976.291143] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFC13023A | uCode revision type
    [  976.291144] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x7B6FD35B | uCode version major
    [  976.291145] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x78E5A989 | uCode version minor
    [  976.291146] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x603FE5F3 | hw version
    [  976.291146] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x981DEEE4 | board version
    [  976.291147] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0EE505E8 | hcmd
    [  976.291148] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xF8735FE1 | isr0
    [  976.291148] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x2EA8F304 | isr1
    [  976.291149] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x6EF1566F | isr2
    [  976.291150] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xD32EE2B5 | isr3
    [  976.291150] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x76EFE972 | isr4
    [  976.291151] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x11003C40 | last cmd Id
    [  976.291152] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x35ADD234 | wait_event
    [  976.291152] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x1C515561 | l2p_control
    [  976.291153] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x6AFA8BEB | l2p_duration
    [  976.291154] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xCE280AA7 | l2p_mhvalid
    [  976.291154] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFF00FF3F | l2p_addr_match
    [  976.291155] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xE3444D19 | lmpm_pmg_sel
    [  976.291156] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x876DCC07 | timestamp
    [  976.291156] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x4F09C528 | flow_handler
    [  976.291384] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
    [  976.291385] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: 532745102
    [  976.291385] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x79F5CE8D | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
    [  976.291386] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x9304FD34 | umac branchlink1
    [  976.291387] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x7F3B0198 | umac branchlink2
    [  976.291388] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFD9013F9 | umac interruptlink1
    [  976.291388] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x357CBF69 | umac interruptlink2
    [  976.291389] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x685424E6 | umac data1
    [  976.291390] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB5F8E658 | umac data2
    [  976.291390] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0ADF3729 | umac data3
    [  976.291391] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xE883FF37 | umac major
    [  976.291392] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x345D2E74 | umac minor
    [  976.291392] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x859FEB8B | frame pointer
    [  976.291393] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xE4AE2224 | stack pointer
    [  976.291394] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x67BEFA77 | last host cmd
    [  976.291394] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xDF66255E | isr status reg
    [  976.291694] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
    [  976.291909] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
    [  976.292066] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
    [  976.292205] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
    [  976.292340] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
    [  976.292476] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
    [  976.292611] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
    [  976.292746] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
    [  976.292881] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
    [  976.293017] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
    [  976.293152] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
    [  976.293288] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
    [  976.293423] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
    [  976.293427] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
    [  976.293429] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
    [  978.532031] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Queue 0 is inactive on fifo 2 and stuck for 2500 ms. SW [163, 164] HW [162, 162] FH TRB=0x0a5a5a5a2
    [  982.054196] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Queue 10 is inactive on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [173, 211] HW [162, 162] FH TRB=0x0a5a5a5a2
    [  986.277482] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14478 end=14479) time 1979 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 991, end 141
[  986.291323] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14480 end=14481) time 2177 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 927, end 121
[  986.568500] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14520 end=14521) time 1390 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 953, end 27
[  986.603338] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14525 end=14526) time 2179 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 868, end 51
[  986.616488] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14527 end=14528) time 1529 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 826, end 1080
[  986.630675] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14529 end=14530) time 2178 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 783, end 1135
[  986.782879] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14551 end=14552) time 1118 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 919, end 1105
[  987.450429] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14647 end=14648) time 1930 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 799, end 1109
[  987.492875] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14653 end=14654) time 2201 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 918, end 105
[  987.520293] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14657 end=14658) time 2213 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 822, end 11
[  987.533777] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14659 end=14660) time 1793 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 799, end 1075
[  987.548498] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14661 end=14662) time 2269 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 941, end 139
[  987.581956] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14666 end=14667) time 2224 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 726, end 1085
[  987.603211] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14669 end=14670) time 2268 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 790, end 1145
[  987.644005] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14675 end=14676) time 2043 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 771, end 1100
[  987.672501] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14679 end=14680) time 2251 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 819, end 14
[  987.707103] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14684 end=14685) time 2315 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 792, end 1155
[  987.790746] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14696 end=14697) time 2200 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 878, end 64
[  987.803546] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14698 end=14699) time 444 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1018, end 1092
[  987.825341] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14701 end=14702) time 1256 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1043, end 84
[  987.929146] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14716 end=14717) time 1123 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 980, end 10
[  988.296879] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14769 end=14770) time 1844 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 818, end 1114
[  988.789619] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14840 end=14841) time 1276 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 915, end 1116
[  988.831854] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14846 end=14847) time 1550 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 862, end 1105
[  988.846654] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14848 end=14849) time 2317 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 898, end 104
[  988.860299] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=14850 end=14851) time 1761 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 971, end 81
[  989.061742] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15554 end=15555) time 1304 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 992, end 37
[  989.464414] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15612 end=15613) time 1257 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 988, end 29
[  989.680225] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15643 end=15644) time 1326 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1051, end 103
[  989.756480] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15654 end=15655) time 1257 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1029, end 70
[  989.818952] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15663 end=15664) time 1262 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1025, end 66
[  989.843486] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: controller timed out
[  989.888383] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15673 end=15674) time 949 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1056, end 34
[  990.228354] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15722 end=15723) time 1257 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 970, end 11
[  990.943898] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15825 end=15826) time 1257 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1011, end 52
[  991.359827] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=15885 end=15886) time 938 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 948, end 1103
[  992.765394] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=16732 end=16733) time 2064 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 781, end 1114
[  992.765394] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=16734 end=16735) time 2314 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 779, end 1142
[  992.765404] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
```

Comment: Can you check `dmesg` output around the time when this happens?

Comment: Ok got `[drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=5361 end=5362) time 1451 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1031, end 93
` Googling got me to try enabling guc in `/etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf` in with `options i915 enable_guc=2`. I'll see if it works.

Comment: @JamesL I edited the post to include the dmesg errors.